# How to filter and sort by dynamically created fields in grid?

Tags: axapta, ax

I am creating a form in a job using

```
Form form;
FormRun formRun;
FormBuildDesign formBuildDesign;
FormBuildDataSource formBuildDataSource;

form = new Form();.
formBuildDataSource = form.addDataSource("Table");

formBuildDesign = form.addDesign("Design");
formBuildDesign.widthMode(1);
formBuildDesign.heightMode(1);
form.design().caption("Caption");
```

I am adding a grid to the form by

```
formBuildGridControl = formBuildDesign.addControl(FormControlType::Grid,"Table Grid");
```

and than fields (they are named F1, F2, …) to this grid by

```
for(ii = 1;   ii < 5; ii++)
{       
    formBuildGridControl.addDataField(formBuildDataSource.id(),fieldName2Id(tableName2id("Table"), strFmt("F%1",ii)));
}
```

Form is created, grid is added and visible but when I try to sort by a field I get

```
Invalid sort field type.
```

and I do not see filter function.

What I need to do to have sorting and filtering available?

I am doing it in Dynamics AX 2012 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your fields of type `String` with size `Memo`?
Sorting by such fields raises exactly that error due to the fact that sorting by this data type is not possible.
Try setting one of this fields to a limited length e.g. 20 and try it again with this field.